# Как добавить переменную в ссылку после POST запроса

Tags: php, post

Помогите, пожалуйста. У меня есть лендинг, на котором идёт приём данных заказа (имя и телефон), после нажатия на кнопку "Заказать" заказ отправляется по API рекламодателю. Отправка происходит POST запросом, после выполнения POST запроса идёт редирект на страницу благодарности. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно добавить переменные в ссылку редиректа.

```html
header( 'Location: http://google.ru/search?name=$name&phone=$phone' );
```

так не работает.

Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Возьмите строчку в двойные кавычки `""`.